# Print SQL query message in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have written a code which contains a SQL query. The SQL query works fine (because I can see the effect on the database). But I want to show the message of the SQL. When we run this query on SQL server, it gives the message below and we understand the query has been executed correctly:
"The query has been executed successfully for the user xxx."

Below is the code I have written for SQL query execution which works fine but I want to be able to print the above message I mentioned.

```
        //SQL Server Connection
        string con_str_reenable = "Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con_db_reenable = new SqlConnection(con_str_reenable);

        //SQL Query:
        string reenable_query="The  query is pasted here(Exec **** XXX)";
        SqlCommand rep_com = new SqlCommand(reenable_query, con_db_reenable);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda1.SelectCommand = rep_com;
            DataTable dbdataset1 = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dbdataset1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Please help me be able to print the message without changing SQL access codes above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's just what SSMS displays.. You can do a similar thing, eg executing a ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of Rows affected - so you could print a message "x number of records updated".

In your example with populating a DataTable you can print out "The query has been executed successfully for the user xxx" every time there isn't an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try [InfoMessage event in SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

Microsoft's sample:

```
// Assumes that connection represents a SqlConnection object.
connection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);

protected static void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgsargs) {
    foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors) {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} has received a severity {1}, state {2} error number {3}\non line {4} of procedure {5} on server {6}:\n{7}",
          err.Source, err.Class, err.State, err.Number, err.LineNumber, err.Procedure, err.Server, err.Message);
    }
}
```

And of course you can use ExecuteNonQuery method which returns how many rows was processed.

Comment: This seems to display everything at the end, after the query has completed. Doesn't seem to be called as 'print' statements run in a stored procedure, for example.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you could use `string.Format`

For example:

```
//Declare variable for storing user string
string username = "xxx"; //You can always change it later

string reenable_query= string.Format("Exec procedure_name @parameter = {0}",username); //{0} will be replaced by the username

SqlCommand rep_com = new SqlCommand(reenable_query, con_db_reenable);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda1.SelectCommand = rep_com;
        DataTable dbdataset1 = new DataTable();
        sda1.Fill(dbdataset1);

        //Show Message *Add here
        string show = string.Format("The query has been executed successfully for the user {0}", username);

        MessageBox.Show(show);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
```

But I recommend using a different method of executing your query, your current code is unprotected from SQL Injections, I suggest you do this

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection())
{
    DataSet tmp = new DataSet();

    connect.ConnectionString = conString;

    connect.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(*your query*, connect);

    adapter.Fill(tmp);
}
```

Comment: I want to print the actual message of the SQL query. For now, I am using string.format as a workaround but I want to get the exact message.

Comment: You can use [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx)